# ¿Cómo hacer que el botón tabulador haga una función dentro del Evento KeyDown?

Tags: c#, evento-keydown, tabulador

Estoy usando el Evento KeyDown en un TextBox, en el cual solamente si se presiona Enter o Tabulador (Tab) haga una función, y pues lo he logrado a medias (literalmente), porque cuando tecleo un código y doy Enter me realiza la función (la que se llama Remilia, Remilia por si se lo preguntan y lo considerasen necesario, lo que hace es que autocompleta unos datos para ya no tener necesidad de llenar otros campos, dichos campos no precisamente tienen que estar en Enabled = False). El punto es que al momento de dar la tecla Tabulador no pues pasa a otro campo (cosa que entiendo que es normal, pero he visto programas similares que hacen esta función que estoy tratando de hacer). Les agradecería mucho su ayuda, sé que no es la gran cosa, pero si me gustaría añadir esta función.

```
private void txtClvOp_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (txtClvOp.Text == "") 
    { }
    else
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter || e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
        {
            Remilia();
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Hay una respuesta publicada, si ha dado con la solución, márcala como aceptada haciendo click en el check del costado de la respuesta. Si no, deja un comentario en la respuesta diciendo qué no funcionó, a veces entre comentarios sale el verdadero origen de la pregunta y como resultado, la respuesta se modifica. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lograr lo que pides debes ubicar tu código en el **evento PreviewKeyDown** (como indica su nombre se ejecuta antes del **evento KeyDown**) del **TextBox**:

```
private void textBox1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyData == Keys.Tab)
    {
        Remilia();
        e.IsInputKey = true;
    }
}
```

Al establecer la **propiedad IsInputKey** se indica que el control debe procesar la tecla como de entrada regular y no mover el foco a otro control.